# Delete all duplicate employee records excluding the most recent record for each employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

[Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU18) (KB5017593) - 15.0.4261.1 (X64)]

I have this query to find all duplicate employee records. A duplicate record is a record with the same EmployeeID as another record in the table.

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,EmployeeID
    ,EmployeeName
    ,BadgeNumber
    ,EffectiveDate

FROM
    [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyEmployeeTable]

WHERE
EmployeeID IN(
    SELECT EmployeeID
    FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyEmployeeTable]
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY EmployeeID, EffDate DESC
```

Here is a hypothetical result of this query.

```
ID      EmployeeID  EmployeeName            BadgeNumber     EffectiveDate
3822    10000001    Example Employee A      19023           2023-07-08
2232    10000001    Example Employee A      19248           2022-01-02
3946    10000005    Example Employee B      19212           2022-01-23
4189    10000005    Example Employee B      19029           2021-11-15
4176    10000005    Example Employee B      19002           2021-11-10
3820    10000010    Example Employee C      12070           2022-03-27
2625    10000010    Example Employee C      19005           2021-11-15
4682    10000055    Example Employee D      12751           2023-01-05
3664    10000055    Example Employee D      12767           2021-11-29
```

You can see that some employees have more than just 1 duplicate record. Sometimes there are many duplicates. I need to delete all duplicate records, leaving only the most recent records (using the EffectiveDate field to determine this). To do this, I want to modify the query so it instead produces this result:

```
ID      EmployeeID  EmployeeName            BadgeNumber     EffectiveDate
2232    10000001    Example Employee A      19248           2022-01-02
4189    10000005    Example Employee B      19029           2021-11-15
4176    10000005    Example Employee B      19002           2021-11-10
2625    10000010    Example Employee C      19005           2021-11-15
3664    10000055    Example Employee D      12767           2021-11-29
```

It is the exact same result as above, only it does not have the most recent employee record for each employee found by the original query. I imagine this would work by selecting just the most recent record for each employee, then selecting all duplicates that are NOT this most recent record -- but I do not know how to get this into a proper query...

Comment: The common way is to use a ROW_NUMBER... Something like: `DELETE t FROM (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC AS sort FROM yourtable) t WHERE t.sort > 1`

Comment: Tip of today: Create a unique constraint.

Comment: @jarlh What do you mean?

Comment: When you have deleted the duplicates from the table, create a unique constraint to prohibit new duplicates to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use window functions for this:

```
select distinct
    first_value(ID)over (partition by EmployeeId order by EffectiveDate desc) as ID,
    EmployeeID,
    EmployeeName,
    first_value(BadgeNumber) over (partition by EmployeeId order by EffectiveDate desc) as BadgeNumber,
    first_value(EffectiveDate) over (partition by EmployeeId order by EffectiveDate desc) as EffectiveDate
from [MyDatabse].[dbo].[MyEmployeeTable]
order by EmployeeID, ID
```

Or, the arguably cleaner window function solution:

```
select
    ID,
    EmployeeID,
    EmployeeName,
    BadgeNumber,
    EffectiveDate
from
(
    select
        ID,
        EmployeeID,
        EmployeeName,
        BadgeNumber,
        EffectiveDate,
        row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId order by EffectiveDate desc) as rowNum
    from [MyDatabse].[dbo].[MyEmployeeTable]
) e
where e.rowNum = 1
```

If you don't like using a subquery, then a cte is also fine:

```
with cte as
(
    select
        ID,
        EmployeeID,
        EmployeeName,
        BadgeNumber,
        EffectiveDate,
        row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId order by EffectiveDate desc) as rowNum
    from [MyDatabse].[dbo].[MyEmployeeTable]
)
select
    ID,
    EmployeeID,
    EmployeeName,
    BadgeNumber,
    EffectiveDate
from cte
where rowNum = 1
```

Alternatively, a `NOT EXISTS` should also work:

```
select *
from [MyDatabse].[dbo].[MyEmployeeTable] e1
where not exists 
(
    select *
    from [MyDatabse].[dbo].[MyEmployeeTable] e2
    where e1.EmployeeID = e2.EmployeeID
    and e2.EffectiveDate > e1.EffectiveDate
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple deletion from a derived table based on a windowed row number over your EmployeeId partition:

```
/*delete from t*/ -- <- replace the select with this after confirming results
select *
from (
  select *, Row_Number() over(partition by EmployeeId order by EffectiveDate desc) rn
  from MyDatabase.dbo.MyEmployeeTable
)t
where rn > 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

Somthing like :

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT
    ID
    ,EmployeeID
    ,EmployeeName
    ,BadgeNumber
    ,EffectiveDate
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC) AS N

FROM
    [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyEmployeeTable]
)
DELETE FROM D
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyEmployeeTable] AS D
     JOIN T ON D.ID = T.ID
WHERE N > 1
```

Comment: you can usually delete from cte right away, no need to double dip the table again